# How to convert base64 string to JPG or Png in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in my Ionic App and I am performing the update profile image using the file input in Ionic.

This is my **updateimage.html**:

```
<ion-content padding style="text-align: center;">
  <ion-grid align-items-center justify-content-center style="height: 100%;">
    <ion-row align-items-center justify-content-center style="height: 100%;">
      <ion-col align-self-center justify-content-center col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-3 style="text-align: center;">
        <h2 class="myformh2">Update Profile Picture</h2>
        <h4 class="myformh2">Image Preview</h4>
        <img src="{{imageUrl}}" class="newimg22" />
        <form [formGroup]="updateprofileimg" (ngSubmit)="changeProfileImage()">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="newitem2">
              <ion-input placeholder="Upload Image" type="file" (change)="onImageSelected($event)"
                [(ngModel)]="img_upload" formControlName="img_upload" required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <div>
              <button [disabled]="!updateprofileimg.valid" ion-button type="submit" class="newbtn11" color="primary"
                block>Change Profile Picture</button>
            </div>
          </ion-list>
        </form>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

In this html, when the user upload the image, I am showing the preview of the image.

This is my **updateimage.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { RestapiProvider } from '../../providers/restapi/restapi';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-updateimage',
  templateUrl: 'updateimage.html',
})
export class UpdateimagePage {
  updateprofileimg : FormGroup;
  img_upload: any = [];
  selectedImage;
  imageUrl;
  converted_image;
  responseEdit: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public restProvider: RestapiProvider,
    private storage: Storage) {
      this.updateprofileimg = this.formBuilder.group({
        img_upload: ['', Validators.required],
      });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad UpdateimagePage');
  }

  onImageSelected(event) {
    this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.imageUrl = e.target.result;
      this.converted_image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+this.imageUrl;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedImage);
  }

  changeProfileImage()
  {
    const fd = new FormData();
    this.storage.get("ID").then((val) =>
    {
      if(val)
      { 
        fd.append('upic', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name);
        this.restProvider.updateprofileimg(fd , 'update_profilepic/'+val).subscribe((data) => {
          if (data) {
            this.responseEdit = data;
            console.log(this.responseEdit.msg);
          }
        });

      }
    });
  }

}
```

In this ts file, I am sending the uploaded image to the backend using API but the problem is that, It is sending the base64 url of the image.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try This:

```
  onImageSelected(event) {
    this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.imageUrl = e.target.result;
      this.converted_image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+this.imageUrl;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedImage);
  }

  changeProfileImage()
  {
    const fd = new FormData();
    this.storage.get("ID").then((val) =>
    {
      if(val)
      { 
        fd.append('upic', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name);
        fd.append('user_id', val);
        this.restProvider.updateprofileimg(fd , 'update_profilepic/'+val).subscribe((data) => {
          if (data) {
            this.responseEdit = data;
            console.log(this.responseEdit.msg);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

This solved my problem.